# I get a this error when running scrapy spider ——> ValueError: time data '2022-10-10T13:00:00-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Tags: python, datetime, scrapy, pythonanywhere

When I run the scrapy spider on my local computer it works perfectly. However, when I run it pyhonanywhere's bash terminal I get the following error.

```
ValueError: time data '2022-10-10T13:00:00-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
```

I'm not sure what the problem is as the format looks correct to me. Any help is appreciated

Comment: what code makes this problem?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FObersteiner  I mentioned that in my answer....

Answer (score 2):

Try Removing the last colon in the timezone should be all you need.  Python didn't add support for the colon until `3.7` so maybe it's running an older version....

```
'2022-10-10T13:00:00-0700'
```

`%z`

> UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object is naive).

examples: `+0000`, `-0400`, `+1030`, `+063415`, `030712.345216`

Comment: @FObersteiner  Yes i made that extremely clear in my answer....